# meaning of "morning too"

Tags: grammar

Why do some people say "morning ***too***" instead of saying "good morning to you too", in response to "good morning"?

Is it grammatically correct and valid to say "good morning **too**" or just "**morning too**"?

Answer (score 1):

"Morning Too" or "Good Morning Too" both sound lazy to me.

Stick with "**Good morning to you, too!**"

My other response to "Good Morning" is "**Hi, how are you doing today?!**".  (People like to be asked about themselves.)

Comment: Probably just response "Good Morning!"

Comment: One person's "lazy" is another person's "friendly" (not unlike the way way one person's "respectful" is another person's "distancing"). Context, of which the OP has given none, is important.

Comment: @choster -- **Agreed**. On this site I find myself regularly sharing my opinion that, unless a person's going to be an English Professor, "perfect grammar" is becoming less and less of a necessity (or a reality). It's more important that others understand _what_ we are trying to communicate, not _how perfectly_ we say it (especially in the world of texting, emails, forums, etc...   Thus, **context** is often the **most** important part.  I'm _constantly_ stopping my child mid-sentence to tell him, "_Wait, I need **more information**!  What are you talking about?  What are you pointing at?"_

Comment: @JR - I'm kind of surprised I included that phrase - thanks for the edit.